# Can't access service from external IPs

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I have amazon EC2 instance.
It has wowza server. All inbound connections in Amazon Security group for ports 1024-65535 are allowed.

Yesterday Wowza stopped to response to connections from external IPs.
Now I can connect to it using `telnet localhost 1935`
But I can't connect to it from different IPs: `telnet hostname.com 1935` doesn't work.

```
ubuntu@media:~$ sudo lsof -i | grep 1935
java 1283 root 60u IPv4 8442 0t0 TCP *:1935 (LISTEN)
```

lsof said that everything is good.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a ticket with Amazon technical support.